# Why my module is loaded when I don't have it imported?

Tags: python, import

Why module is loaded when I don have it connected?

When i started my program, first is loaded

> game_character.py

and next

> Game_with_map_function.py

Should be the other way round

> game_character.py

```
NO IMPORTS HERE
def StworzBohatera():
    wybor_1 = input("Rycerz[1], Mag[2], Lucznik[3]")
    while wybor_1 != '1' and wybor_1 != '2' and wybor_1 != '3':
        print("Niepoprawna cyfra")

    if wybor_1 == '1':
        bohaterAtak = 100
        bohaterObrona = 50

    elif wybor_1 == '2':
        bohaterAtak = 50
        bohaterObrona = 100

    elif wybor_1 == '3':
        bohaterAtak = 75
        bohaterObrona = 75

    name = input("Podaj nazwe uzytkownika")

    return (bohaterAtak, bohaterObrona, name)


class_data = StworzBohatera()

character = Bohater(100, 100, 100, class_data[0], class_data[1], 10, 0, 1)
print(character.getObrona(), character.getAtak(), character.getMana())
```

In

> Game_with_map_function.py

I don't have import StworzBohatera

> game_information.py

```
from game_player_atributes import level_up 
from game_character import character
```

> game_player_atributes.py

```
from game_character import character as nasz_bohater
```

> game_stage_open_chest.py

```
from game_information import Zmienne
import random
import math
from enum import Enum
import gold_chances_variables
from game_character import nasz_bohater
from game_player_atributes import level_up
```

Comment: Please update your question with at least some of the files that are loaded. There must be some imports somewhere.

Comment: I eddited my code

Comment: Ok, the line: `from game_character import character as nasz_bohater` doesn't just go and find `character`, it reads the whole of `game_character.py` and *then* it tries to find `character` (which is `character = Bohater(...`) and then gives it the name `nasz_bohater`. But now its too late. Everything else has been imported, which I think you've guessed since you must be seeing the output of the `print()` on the next line.

Comment: Is there any solution to be loaded other way round?

Comment: What do you mean `"loaded other way round"`? You could split out all the independent parts into different files. (btw, you have: `character = Bohater(...`. What is `Bohater`? Is that imported?)